# Ethical code in biathlon?

Tags: biathlon

Does it exists in biathlon a sort of ethical code that prevents the athlete to leave a race even if the final results is very compromised?

In the today Mass Start (16 gen 2016 in Ridnaun-Val Ridanna) Bjorndalen has 2+3+2+3 error for the 4 sessions. I do not think that the points raised in today's race from Bjornadalen can be important for general or specialty rankings so I do not understand why he is not leave after the 2nd / 3rd lap.

It is not a good show to view the most important biathlete of ever to run alone in the last position

I was wondering if withdraw during the race was seen as a lack of respect for the public or for other competitors

Comment: I don't see how there's an ethical dimension to this question. Bjorndalen's actions aren't going to affect anyone else, so he can do whatever he feels like.

Comment: I was asking if was a "dishonor" to abandon during the race